# Can't work with gloox library in ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu-12.04, gloox

Some time ago I installed gloox library with the command sudo apt-get install libgloox-dev.
But it is not working in netbeans, for example. I noticed that there are only .h files (with only function declarations) in /usr/include/gloox directory. Need your help...

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? You have a program that's not compiling, or not linking, or what? You've installed the lib -dev package, have you installed the libgloox8 itself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your project dependencies in order to use a library.
Are you able to access Gloox files using <> ? If yes the environment variable is set correctly (should be done automatically in Ubuntu)

The library (.so file) will be in /usr/local/lib. You need to link the project against it in your makefile. On netbeans I *think* it's on project properties->c++ compiler. Personally, I use Cmake to generate my makefiles

Answer (score 0):

Try to download library from http://camaya.net/gloox/download and follow installation instructions.